# Double dot product of the gradient of a vector with itself

Tags: calculus, tensors

So I came across this expression:
$$
\nabla\mathbf{A}:\nabla\mathbf{A}=\partial_iA_j\partial_iA_j.
$$
I tried doing the double sum on paper to see what it looks like but I'm unsure about something. Is this expression the square of the norm of the gradient of $\mathbf{A}$? Ie. do we have:
$$
\nabla\mathbf{A}:\nabla\mathbf{A}=|\nabla\mathbf{A}|^2,
$$
so that is a positive quantity?

I'm also curious about the related expression:
$$
\nabla\mathbf{A}:(\nabla\mathbf{A})^{\top}=\partial_iA_j\partial_jA_i.
$$
Which I assume is not the same thing at all. But I think this is not sign definite?

Can we give interpretations to both these quantities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once we define $\nabla\mathbf{A}$ as the matrix whose ${}_{ij}$ entry is $\partial_iA_j$, you're right: $\nabla\mathbf{A}:\nabla\mathbf{A}$ is just the sum of the squares of the entries of this matrix. Of course, any square matrices $B,\,C$ satisfy$$B:C=B_{ij}C_{ij}=B_{ij}C^\top_{ji}=[BC^\top]_{ii}=\operatorname{tr}[BC^\top],$$so $\nabla\mathbf{A}:\nabla\mathbf{A}=\operatorname{tr}[\nabla\mathbf{A}(\nabla\mathbf{A})^\top]$ as well. Similarly,$$\nabla\mathbf{A}:\nabla\mathbf{A}^\top=\operatorname{tr}[(\nabla\mathbf{A})^2].$$This is indeed sign-indefinite; consider e.g. the cases $\mathbf{A}=\left(\begin{array}{c}y\\\pm x\end{array}\right)$, for which$$\nabla\mathbf{A}:\nabla\mathbf{A}^T=\operatorname{tr}[\pm I_2]=\pm2.$$

Comment: Great thanks! This answers my question.